# Meaning of “dofhoadayne” in 1648 Will of William Noake from Longburton, Dorset, England?

Tags: england, palaeography, will, dorset, 1640s

The man I believe to be my 9th great grandfather **William Noake** wrote his **Will** on **2 Jan 1648** at **Longburton, Dorset, England**, and a cropped image from very near the beginning of that document appears below.

[image]

- The first word is easy: ***husbandman***
- The last five words are easy: ***this my last will and***

It is the word in between that I am yet to decipher but it seems to be something like "***dofhoadayne***".

Does anyone know what this word is likely to be?

It comes from this larger sample:

[image]

If you need particular sample letters from elsewhere in the document just ask for clarification via comments and I am happy to add a few more samples.

---

After accepting the answer of @RustyErpenbeck, and help from @bgwiehle with the difficult to read (at least for me) "church yarde", the above now reads to me as:

> of Longburton in the county of Dorset husbandman ***doth ordayne***
>   this my last will and Testament in manner and formt following viz I
>   give and bequeath my soul unto Allmighty God who gave it me and my
>   bodie to be buried in Christian buriall in the parish church yarde
>   of Long Burton from I give to the parish church of Long Burton Two
>   shillings from

Comment: Add a few more lines of the will and that may help

Comment: The start of the word may actually be "d of ...", given the proximity of the other words. Any other examples of the handwriting available?

Comment: If you add additional samples, could you ensure that "r" "D" "m" are represented. Does the writer use many superscripts?

Comment: It would help if we could have a the complete sentence for grammatical context.  Also see [alphabets](http://paleo.anglo-norman.org/empfram.html) for comparison purposes.

Comment: @bgwiehle The letters you asked for should now all be present in the larger sample that I just added.  There do not seem to be (m)any superscripts in the document.

Comment: Original missing phrase may be "...do this day me..." but that doesn't make total sense. Other missing phrase is "church-yarde".

Comment: @bgwiehle Now I see that!  Many thanks!  I'll edit into my question so it can stay standalone.

Comment: Also the National Archives tutorial has a section on [Abbreviations](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/palaeography/where_to_start.htm#abbreviations).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It says "**Doth Ordayne**" as in "I doeth Ordain this my Last Will and Testament"

example - William Shakespeare's Will of 1616 - "I, William Shackspeare of Stratford-upon-Avon in the county of Warwick, gent., in perfect health and memory, God be praised, do make and ordain this my last will and testament"

Comment: I think you're right! That seems to fit a little better than the other answer and a [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Doth+Ordayne#q=Doth+Ordayne+will+testament) turns up some similar phrasing from around the same period.

Comment: The resemblance to "**doth** make constitute and **ordayne this my last will and testament in manner and form following**. First **I give bequeath** and commit **my soul** into hands and protection of the Lord Jesus my only redeemer and my body solemnly to be buried within the parish church of Upton" from [Gloucester (1586)](https://familysearch.org/photos/stories/1556810) is striking.

Comment: This sounds better than my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I read it simply as **do this day**.

Thus some sort of contraction of *Do this day make this, my last will and testament*.

I have a couple of wills from that area of Dorset from just after 1700.  They use very similar phraseology.